# Matching arithmetic expressions in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog, clpfd, integer-arithmetic

I have an arithmetic expression containing `Var`, and I need to match it to the following format:

`Step * Var + Offset`

If it can be represented in this form, I need to get `Step` and `Offset` values. If not, I need to know that too.

So far I tried matching expression trees, i. e.

```
Expression = ["+", ["*", Var, Step], Offset] % and other variations
```

and using CLP(FD):

```
78 ?- 2*Ind+3 #= Step*Ind+Offset, Ind in inf..sup.            
Step*Ind#=_A,
2*Ind#=_B,
_B+3#=_C,
_A+Offset#=_C.
```

However, the first approach would require simplifying expressions (for example, Var+5-3) and handling multiple different cases, and the second does not work as I expected it to.

Am I missing something? Is there a simpler way, or is this problem too complex?

Comment: Where is the expression created? Sounds like it would be easier to control its format at the point of creation.

Comment: `?- Step*Var + Offset = 5*10+20.` gives Step = 5, Var = 10, Offset = 20. Prolog terms are not nested lists like your expression tree, they are nested compound terms; `?- +(*(Step,Var),Offset) = 5*10+20.`

Comment: @brebs these expressions are initially created by users, and I cannot add any format restrictions, unfortunately.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I don't match Prolog terms, I convert expressions to the same tree format. (in my expample, `Expression` would be something like `["*", Var, 2]`). Comparing Prolog terms would not work for expressions that don't follow the `Step*Var+Offset` structure for the same reason (for example `?- (2*Var+1)-1 = Step*Var+Offset.` is false).